# Flask has many through model associations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Ruby on Rails has a has-many-through association. For example,

```
store has_many :shelves
shelf has many :books
store has_many :books, through: :shelves
```

This would allow us to call `store.books` and get all the books in the store. I am looking to replicate this functionality in Flask, but can't seem to find the information.

For example, here are the one to many relationships written in Python. Store has many shelves, shelves has many books.

```
class Store(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    shelves = db.relationship('Shelf', backref='store')

class Shelf(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id'), nullable=False)
    books = db.relationship('Book', backref='shelf')

class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    shelf_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('shelf.id'), nullable=False)
```

With the code currently as written, I can call `store.shelves` and `shelf.books`. However, to get to books, I would have to loop through the shelves and call `.books`.

Is there a way to call `store.books` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `Shelf` as a "secondary" table and create a one-sided "many-to-many" relationship, though really a one-to-many relationship with a table in between:

```
class Store(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    shelves = db.relationship('Shelf', backref='store')
    books = db.relationship('Book', secondary='shelf', viewonly=True)
```

It is better to treat the relationship as a view only, since there is no way to decide which shelf a book should go to, if appended to the `Store.books` list. This comes fairly close to how Rails handles defining the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through shelves would be very inefficient. Leave it to your database engine.

You need to create a custom query to achieve that. If you want to call it with `store.books` you can create property in `Store` class:

```
class Store(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    shelves = db.relationship('Shelf', backref='store')

    @property
    def books(self):
        query = Book.query.join(Shelf).join(Store).filter(Store.id == self.id)
        return query.all()
```

Comment: i thought about that. I was mostly wondering if there is a flask function built in (like Rails) that can handle this situation. Sounds like that isn't the case?